# Hive table always set column comment is "from deserializer"

Tags: hadoop, hive, opencsv

I execute query to create Hive table below:

```
CREATE TABLE db1.test_create_tbl( column1 smallint COMMENT 'desc of column')
COMMENT 'desc of table'
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

I execute query to display table schema below:

```
DESCRIBE db1.test_create_tbl
```

But when i get table schema, column description always display "from deserializer"

Please touch me, thanks

Comment: It was a bug, fixed in 0.13 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6681 but it was reported it still reproducing in 1.1 version: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36593395/2700344

Comment: Thanks you, What should I do now?

Answer (score 2):

I have come across same issue. I have changed the hive configuration and it worked fine.

set the below parameter in hive shell.

set hive.serdes.using.metastore.for.schema=org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde;

Comment: I have got another issue . I am able to see the comments in the table  in beeline but when  I do describe formatted on hue I am still seeing the "from deserializer".